# Configuration to enable tracing in Spring Kafka 3

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, open-telemetry

I am trying to enable Observability in a Kafka Template to create spans for events.I'm using a local instance of Jaeger. In the Jaeger instance I can see spans related to interactions with an S3 bucket, but nothing from interactions with Kafka. When I check the events in the Kafka Topics they do not have any headers containing spanId's or traceId's.

I have set
`kafkaTemplate.setObservationEnabled(true)'`. And I have added the following to application.properties

```
management.tracing.enabled=true
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
management.tracing.propagation.type=w3c
management.tracing.propagation.produce=w3c
management.tracing.propagation.consume=w3c
management.otlp.tracing.endpoint=http://localhost:4318/v1/traces
```

and I have added the following dependecies to service

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.1 and Spring Kafka 3.1.1.

I'm mostly following this guide here:
https://piotrminkowski.com/2023/11/15/kafka-tracing-with-spring-boot-and-open-telemetry/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Generalize Answer**
The `kafkaTemplate` instance must be a bean managed by Spring. If so the afterSingletonsInstantiated method will be called with will set the ObservationRegistry object in place of the default ObservationRegistry.NOOP.